# Django Templates: Form field name as variable?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

How can I make this loop to print form fields where XXXXXXXX is the value of ticket.id?

```
{% for ticket in zone.tickets %}
    {{ ticket.id }}: {{ form.ticket_count_XXXXXXXX }}
{% endfor %}
```

So the output to be something like this...

```
1: <input ... name="ticket_count_1">
10: <input ... name="ticket_count_10">
12: <input ... name="ticket_count_12">
3: <input ... name="ticket_count_3">
```

Comment: I like this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12307727/177293

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass arguments in the django template, so no.

You'd need to implement a template tag (more of a pain) or filter, or make the association from `ticket` to `formfield` in your view (what I would recommend).

Since I don't actually know the relationship between `ticket` and your form fields, I can't tell what the best method is, but this would 'just work' based on the info you've provided.

```
# view
form = MyForm()
for ticket in zone.tickets:
    ticket.form_field = form['ticket_count_' + str(ticket.id)]

# template
{% for ticket in zone.tickets %}
    {{ ticket.id }} : {{ ticket.form_field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This looks like it will work "#ticket['form_field'] = purchaseForm.fields['ticket_' + str(ticket['id'])];" but insted of field HTML I get "<django.forms.fields.IntegerField object at 0x017938D0>"

Comment: oops, yeah, I meant to say getattr(form, 'attr')

Comment: Yeah, don't do form.fields['field']-- that will literally get you the field object, not the BoundField object that prints as a widget

Comment: There we go, try: `ticket.form_field = form['ticket_count_' + str(ticket.id)]`, that will get you the `BoundField` you need