# Django templates: How to access a form field equal to a variable value?

Tags: django, django-templates

Imagine a following use case: I have a dictionary of report templates. Each report template has an ID and a name. It looks more or less like this:

```
reports = [ { 'ID' : 'A1',
              'NAME' : 'special report 1 for department A',
              ... (other fields irrelevant to the question's matter)
            },
            { 'ID' : 'X9',
              'NAME' : 'special report 9 for department X',
              ... (other fields irrelevant to the question's matter)
            },
          ]
```

Access to and visibility of the reports are to be stored in a database.
I created a form with field names equal to reports' IDs. And everything goes fine until the moment I have to show the form in the template. I don't know how to access the proper form's field. This syntax doesn't work:

```
{% for report in reports %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ report.ID }}</td>
    <td>{{ report.NAME }}</td>

    <td>{{ form.report.ID }}</td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Also:

```
{% for report in reports %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ report.ID }}</td>
    <td>{{ report.NAME }}</td>
    {% with report.ID as key %}     
    <td>{{ form.key }}</td>
    {% endwith %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

doesn't work.

How should the syntax look like? What should be placed instead of the question marks in the code below?

```
{% for report in reports %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ report.ID }}</td>
    <td>{{ report.NAME }}</td>

    <td>{{ form.??? }}</td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I crossed upon this solution: [Django Templates: Form field name as variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993625/django-templates-form-field-name-as-variable) and I guess I'll have to use it if there won't be any other way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's discouraged because the templates are supposed to be as without logic as possible. But, in practice, this comes up all the time.  You can make a template filter that does this:

```
@register.filter(name='get')
def get(o, index):
    try:
        return o[index]
    except:
        return settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID
```

Then, in the template, after you load the templatetags library appropriately:

```
{% for report in reports %}
<tr>
    ...
    <td>{{ form|get:report.ID }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It worked. It doesn't solve the problem (basically you can't access fields the way I planned) but the custom filter does the similar job. Thaks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{ form.fields.key }}
```

Comment: I tried 
{% with report.ID as key %} 
{{ form.fields.key }}
{% endwith %}
and 
{{ form.fields.report.ID }}. 
Both don't work :/

Comment: Oh, right, your "key" is a variable, not a symbol. In this case, you'll have to make your own template tag or filter, unfortunately.

Comment: It would be a terrible overkill :/

Comment: On the other hand, manipulating the form like this in template seems not very productive. Maybe describe the task you want to accomplish?

Comment: Imagine a set of objects. Each with it's own business logic. They are stored in a dictionary and distinguished by unique IDs. Users are to have access to all, some or none of them. I'm writing a tool that stores the following data in a database: "user-report-access granted/access denied".

Comment: fields dict does not contain the bound fields that render their widgets appropriately.